# WooCommerce - Subscriptions Add custom field in Edit Subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using [Wordpress WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) plugins and it's working as per my expectations.

However, I had a requirement to add a custom field in the **Edit Subscription** page hence I followed the below hook and code to add my new field in the **Edit Subscription** page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'showWCSubscriptionCustomFields');




function showWCSubscriptionCustomFields($subscription) {

    $currentPage = get_current_screen();

    // If page is "Edit Subscription" page, then only show 
    if ($currentPage->action == 'add')
        return;

    // Getting all the users 
    $mindeskUsers = getAllUsers();

?>
    <br class="clear" />
    <p class="form-field form-field-wide">
        <label for="mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id">Mindesk VAR Client User:</label>
        <?php

        $selectedUser = get_post_meta($subscription->get_id(), 'mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id', true);

        echo getUsersListSelect('mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id', $selectedUser, $mindeskUsers, 'mindesk_select2');
        ?>
    </p>
<?php

}
```

This is working fine for me .. Here I am checking if the page is not in **add** more and it will show my custom field only when the page is in Edit mode. So in **Edit Subscription** page, its showing my custom field and I am able to save the data using below hook.

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'saveWCSubscriptionCustomFields');

function saveWCSubscriptionCustomFields($subscription_id) {

    // wc_clean() and wc_sanitize_textarea() are WooCommerce sanitization functions 
    update_post_meta($subscription_id, 'mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id', wc_clean($_POST['mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id']));
}
```

Now my query is, when I am going in to **Edit Order** page, then also I am able to see this new field. I do not want to show this new custom field in this page.

I have tried to find various hooks and tried a few but none of them working for me properly.

Can someone guide me how can I show my new custom field only in **Edit Subscription** -page .. and how can I hide this new field for **Edit Order** Page ?

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can hide by CSS.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Bhautik .. what should I do to check in css ?

Comment: This `Mindesk VAR Client User:` field you want to hide?

Comment: yes exactly .. ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this two-class `hide-if-admin` and `mindesk-var` to your `p` tag. check the below code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'showWCSubscriptionCustomFields');
function showWCSubscriptionCustomFields($subscription) {

    $currentPage = get_current_screen();

    // If page is "Edit Subscription" page, then only show 
    if ($currentPage->action == 'add')
        return;

    // Getting all the users 
    $mindeskUsers = getAllUsers();

?>
    <br class="clear" />
    <p class="form-field form-field-wide mindesk-var hide-if-admin">
        <label for="mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id">Mindesk VAR Client User:</label>
        <?php

        $selectedUser = get_post_meta($subscription->get_id(), 'mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id', true);

        echo getUsersListSelect('mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id', $selectedUser, $mindeskUsers, 'mindesk_select2');
        ?>
    </p>
<?php

}

function hide_mindesk_var_client_user(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .post-type-shop_order .mindesk-var.hide-if-admin{display: none;}
    </style>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'hide_mindesk_var_client_user', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: no .. its not working .. its still showing in edit order page

Comment: Can you share the screenshots of the edit order page and code as well?

Comment: sure let me share

Comment: Actually its removing from both .. Edit subscription page as well as Edit Order page ..

Comment: I want to show in **Edit Subscription** page .. and hide only in **Edit Orders** page

Comment: can you share Edit subscription page screenshots by inspect element?

Comment: sure ... let me share

Comment: This seems to be working for me Bhautik .. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yea .. Thanks .. I have another question which I am about to ask soon in this forum .. may be you can help me .. I will share a link here .. Thanks

Comment: Yea Thanks .. Can you please check this thread and guide me what should I do here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66950465/woocommerce-subscriptions-how-to-check-if-product-product-type-is-simple-subscri