# WooCommerce subscriptions: Check if product type is a simple subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-subscriptions

With WooCommerce I am using [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) plugin. I have mainly **Variable Subscription** products and some few simple Subscription products.

I am using `woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args` filter hook, to update dropdown attribute values on my **Variable Subscription** products.

For **Simple Subscriptions** products I would like to add some conditions to allow or deny access to the product page.

**So my question is:** Which hook could I use to check if a product is a simple subscription, to allow or deny access to the product?

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check product type on the `WC_Product` object for **simple subscription** like:

```
if( $product->get_type() === 'subscription' ) {
    // Do something
}
```

or

```
if( $product->is_type('subscription') ) {
    // Do something
}
```

And here below is an example usage that will avoid access to simple subscription product pages, redirecting customer to main shop page and displaying an error notice:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'conditional_single_product_page_access');
function conditional_single_product_page_access(){
    // Targeting single product pages
    if ( is_product() ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() ); // Get the WC_Product Object

        // Targeting simple subscription products
        if( $product->get_type() === 'subscription' ) {
            wc_add_notice( __("You are not allowed to access this product"), 'error' ); // Notice
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); // Redirection
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Notes:**

- To target **variable subscription** product type use the slug `variable-subscription`.
- To target a **variation subscription**, the product type slug is: `subscription_variation`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. . Thank you so much for your help .. It worked for me .. Did not know who has downvoted my question because I have explained everything what I have done and tried so far. Anyways .. Thanks for your support and guidance. Thanks

Comment: Hello Sir, If you can guide me what should I do here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057179/wordpress-woocommerce-add-new-field-in-each-row-at-my-account-subscriptions-pa it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_subscription()` of `WC_Subscriptions_Product`. You need to pass `$product` object in is_subscription() function as parameter. Check the below code.

```
if( WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription( $product ) ) {
    // product is subscription.
} else {
    // product is not subscription.
}
```

**Update**

Use `woocommerce_product_is_visible` filter hook for remove the product from product catalog. check below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_product_if_is_subscription', 20, 2 );
function hide_product_if_is_subscription( $is_visible, $product_id ){
    if( WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription( $product_id ) ) {    
        $is_visible = false;
    }
    return $is_visible;
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WC_Subscriptions_Product' not found `

Comment: Where do you use it?

Comment: isnt there any hook available only for simple subscription product instead of checking with if condition ?

Comment: I want to use the code in one of my custom plugins...

Comment: Yes, but where it will affect? can you share the page link?

Comment: it will effect on product front page of the website .. something like this single product page `http://localhost/wordpress/product/new-product-test/`

Comment: Where did you use it? can you share the code as well?

Comment: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/ it should be something like this ..

Comment: No, I mean in your custom plugin how yo use it?

Comment: In my custom plugin, first i need to check if from backend, I have added Product as "Simple Subscription" .. then if I click on view product.. I should be able to use something like `wp_die('Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.');` to disallow users to execute product page at front ..

Comment: Something like this https://paste.ee/p/VzBvS single product if it is "Simple subscription" product, then it should not be accessible.

Comment: This is how I add "Simple Subscription" product https://ibb.co/vw0L6kp

Comment: wait i will back to you.

Comment: So if any user from frontend website, view the product. as per my custom coding conditions, I will restrict them to execute the page if product is simple subscription product by using something like `wp_die()`

Comment: If you use this hook `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` then after all content will not rendered.

Comment: this hook wont help me much . i want whole page should be restricted ..

Comment: Additionally, this hook also executes for variable subscription products .. so it wont be usefull for me either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230749/discussion-between-bhautik-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Comment: are you still around Bhautik ?

Comment: I do not want to hide any product  .. but instead user should be go inside product page and can access and see my message. if any ..

Comment: Hello Sir, If you can guide me what should I do here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057179/wordpress-woocommerce-add-new-field-in-each-row-at-my-account-subscriptions-pa it would be great. Thanks