# WordPress AJAX update custom field in custom page

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress to update my custom field with AJAX and jQuery using dropdown change event and it's working fine as per my requirements. Here is my working code.

**my-subscriptions.php** page

```
<?php 

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/mindesk-ecommerce/assets/js/custom.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
$ajaxPageUrl =  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); 

?>

<select id="myid" class="mySubscription" name="mindesk_wc_subscriptions_var_client_user_id" data-action="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" data-subscription-id="635"><option value=""></option><option value="24">mittul</option><option value="10">subscriber</option></select>
```

**custom.js**

```
var prev_val;

jQuery('.mySubscription').focus(function() {
    prev_val = jQuery(this).val();
}).change(function() {
    
     jQuery(this).blur() 
    var success = confirm('Are you sure you want to transfer?');
    if(success)
    {
        var subscriptionId = jQuery(this).data("subscription-id");
        var url = jQuery(this).data("action");        
        var userId = jQuery(this).val();        
        jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,           
            data : {
                    action : 'update_subscription_custom_meta',
                    userId : userId,
                    subscriptionId : subscriptionId
            },
           success: function(data)
           {  
              var data = JSON.parse(data);               

               if(data.status == '1')
               {                  
                   alert('Transferred Successfully!!!');
               } 
               else
               {
                   alert('There is some problem transferring the subscription!!!');
               }
           }
         });

    }  
    else
    {
        jQuery(this).val(prev_val);     
        return false; 
    }
});
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_subscription_custom_meta', 'update_subscription_custom_meta' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_subscription_custom_meta', 'update_subscription_custom_meta' );

function update_subscription_custom_meta() {
    update_post_meta($_POST['subscriptionId'], 'my_custom_field', $_POST['userId']);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1),true);
    exit;
}
```

As you can see in **my-subscriptions.php** file I have used

```
$ajaxPageUrl =  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');
```

And based on `mySubscription` class in **custom.js** file, I have used `update_subscription_custom_meta` as `action` and then going into **functions.php** file to update my custom meta data. This all working fine.

But when I change `$ajaxPageUrl` to something like below

```
$ajaxPageUrl = get_template_directory_uri() . '/mindesk-ecommerce/ajax/updatesubscription.php';
```

And then created the file `updatesubscription.php` and put same code which I put above in `functions.php` file then its not working.

It keeps giving me 500 error.. Can someone guide me .. is it possible or ideal way to put code of functions.php to one of my page ..

I want to follow the structure in that way.

Can someone guide me how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: did you check the error logs?

Comment: no logs .. i want to use the same code in my custom page **updatesubscription.php** which i added in **functions.php** file for my updating custom field. i do not want to use **functions.php** .. instead add code from that to my **updatesubscription.php** file which I created. Is it possible or right way ?

Comment: in functions.php you added an ajax action that will not found in updatesubscription.php that's why you got an error.

Comment: yea .. I understand this . so what should I do ?

Comment: Why do you want to call ajax from `updatesubscription.php`

Comment: to make my custom logic in my custom files only you know ..

Comment: is it ideal way how i want ? or this is the ideal way which I have followed so far ? please confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `updatesubscription.php` in your function.php file

```
include( get_template_directory() . '/mindesk-ecommerce/ajax/updatesubscription.php' );
```

And `ajaxPageUrl` As you use in the my-subscriptions.php file

```
$ajaxPageUrl =  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');
```

Comment: Hi Bhautik , can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109228/wordpress-add-custom-div-in-my-account-page-only .. I have shown you my try there . Thanks